# How to assign yesterday's date to a parameter C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2000

I have a C# program that will run as a windows scheduled task.  This program will load, run a SQL Query, email the results stored in the dataset, and then close.  I have everything except the using Yesterdays date.

Here is my current Query:

```
SELECT        Store_Id, Paid_Out_Amount, Paid_Out_Comment, Paid_Out_Datetime, Update_UserName, Till_Number, @startdate AS Start, @enddate AS Today
FROM            Paid_Out_Tb
WHERE        (Store_Id = 1929) AND (Paid_Out_Datetime BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate)
```

Obviously I need to assign @startdate and @enddate at the time of the query.  Since I will need 12AM to 1159PM that is the reason for the start and end.  So for example.  If I want to run the program today it would search yesterday (the 23rd) so @startdate would be assigned 7/22/12 00:00:00 and @enddate would be assigned 7/22/12 23:59:59...

Would it make more sense to do it in the query instead of the program?  If so how would I change the query?

Comment: Don't use BETWEEN. Please read https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx and https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `between` when dealing with date intervals. It is much easier and safer to use `>=` and `<`.

Something like this will give you yesterday stuff without parameters.

```
SELECT Store_Id, Paid_Out_Amount, Paid_Out_Comment, Paid_Out_Datetime, Update_UserName, Till_Number, @startdate AS Start, @enddate AS Today
FROM   Paid_Out_Tb
WHERE  Store_Id = 1929 AND 
       Paid_Out_Datetime >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate())-1, 0) and
       Paid_Out_Datetime < dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Comment: I Went with this... Cleaner at point of gathering the data.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Slight improvement on the existing answers, to always get the *start* of yesterday without having to call the `DateTime` constructor.

```
var todayStart = DateTime.Today;
var yesterdayStart = todayStart.AddDays(-1);
var yesterdayEnd = todayStart.AddSeconds(-1); // Ick...
```

Note that this will use the current system time zone for the meaning of "today" - are you sure that's what you want? You may wish to consider using:

```
var todayUtcStart = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
...
```

It's a shame that `BETWEEN` treats the end point as inclusive - if it were equivalent to

```
start <= value && value < end
```

then you could just give two midnight values, which would be a lot clearer.

Also note that while it wouldn't make interacting with the database any cleaner, for *other* uses of dates and times, you may wish to consider my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library, which contains a data type specifically for representing a *date* (and another for "time of day") etc. The *aim* is certainly to clarify code using dates and times. If it doesn't, I've failed!

Comment: SQL Server stores fraction of seconds by default, so -1 second won't fix it.  Better pass the start of the next day and use `<` instead of `<=`

Comment: @Andomar: I was just going by the question. That's why I was saying that it's a pain that BETWEEN is effectively `<=`. Grr.

Answer (score 4):

You could calculate the start of yesterday in C#:

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
var startOfYesterday = new DateTime(yesterday.Year, yesterday.Day, yesterday.Month);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", startOfYesterday);
```

If you're using SQL Server 2008+, you can change the datatype from `datetime` to `date`.  The later can only store dates, so you won't have to worry about the datetime part.

Comment: Use `Today` instead of `Now` and you don't need to do the "start of yesterday" calculation.

Comment: It's SQL 2000, I'll try the suggestion in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you all looking for something this way

```
DateTime yesterdDaysDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use parameterized queries.

In order to support what you are looking for you can drop in yesterdays date into a variable and pass that variable to your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This might also work, however with a performance drawback:

```
 DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today;
 Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in SQL:

```
SELECT Store_Id, Paid_Out_Amount, Paid_Out_Comment, 
        Paid_Out_Datetime, Update_UserName, Till_Number, @startdate AS Start, @enddate AS Today
FROM            Paid_Out_Tb
WHERE        (Store_Id = 1929) 
AND (Paid_Out_Datetime BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) 
    AND dateadd(second, -1, DATEADD(dd, 1, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put in the query itself:

```
select (date_trunc('day', NOW()) - INTERVAL '1 day'); -- Yesterday Start
select (date_trunc('day', NOW()) - INTERVAL '1 second'); -- Yesterday End
```

Comment: That's Oracle syntax right?  I believe the question is for SQL Server